# Trying to read web page with HttpClient

Tags: c#, web-scraping, httpclient

I try to read some web pages with HttpClient (C#) and with some pages I get **Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (No such file)**? Other work just fine.

Here is the sample of code:

```
            static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private static async void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://www.yourwebpage.com";

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

also try to add Header to client, with no success:

```
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "www.betexplorer.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
```

**Solution:**

I fix this problem with using RestSharp library.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code and hqve ,ore detqils on the pages you're requesting.

Comment: That usually means the URL you used is wrong. Not much more to it than that. What do you want us to say? We have no idea what URLs you tried, or how you used them in the code, so it's not like we can point out any mistakes

Comment: Btw, writing a statement and then putting a question mark on the end (as you've done here) doesn't magically turn it into a real question. All you've done is tell us your troubles. You haven't asked anything or given any information which we could use to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **solution**.
I used RestSharp library and it work perfectly.

```
  private static async void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://www.yourwebpage.com";

        try
        {
            var restClient = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);

            restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            });

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to pretend to be a browser.
For example, add the following header

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0");
```

Comment: No, this doesn't make any difference.